# OpenGl, Alpha blending on the same mesh

Tags: opengl

I am currently writing a model viewer for the game Final Fantasy XIV. I've run into an issue that I am trying to currently solve.

The hair models are all stored as a single mesh. Various layers are placed on top of each other to create a more realistic effect. Then an alpha is applied for the fine threads.

Now the issue I am running into is when I apply the alpha, it turns out like this:

[image: Model]

What's happening is instead of replacing/blending the fragment with the layer below, it is doing it with the clear color probably because there is nothing in the buffer at the time (it's a single mesh remember). How would I go about fixing this issue? Rendering it twice?

Comment: sort the faces back to front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many thing that you can do, but not knowing the requirements I will just list a few:

- OIT: order independent transparency, it requires a bit of setup and it's not easy to do and it has some costs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency
- don't use blending: I know that you probably thought of this, but what if instead of using blending you use alpha testing? Is the aliasing that bad? it's still and option
- a little bit of both, alpha testing and blending. I would recommend this one and I'll quickly explain it below

What I would suggest is based on the AMD Hair Rendering paper available at:

http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Scheuermann_HairRendering.pdf

The paper explains the lighting model first, but then explains the technique used to render hair with alpha blending.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'd like to get the model to render as close to the game produces as possible. Using alpha testing (you mean with discard yes?), I not only get bad aliasing, some parts you see the hair threads with gaps in between.

Comment: I may have fixed the issue. I forgot to enable GL_CULL_FACE which I guess was causing extra face to get drawn. After it was enabled most of the graphical glitches I was experiencing have disappeared. Here is the model now: http://i.imgur.com/EWLdxrH.png

Still, thanks for the ATi link, will be a good read.